# iOS 8 Screen slides wrong direction when back button tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, ios8

My application was written for iOS7 and I am trying to get it updated to iOS 8. My application is configured to only work in Landscape Left and Landscape Right orientations.

For iOS 8 I changed the order by which the screens are navigated and changed one of the modal screens to a push transition. On the main screen I have two UIBarButtonItems on the UINavigationItem. Each of these have a push segue assigned to them that connects to different screens.

When the app is running and one of the UIBarButtonItems is tapped, the screen associated through the segue slides over the main screen as expected.  The back button is displayed normally. The problem occurs when the back button is tapped. The screen does not slide off to the right as would be expected.

On an iPhone 4 running iOS 7 the screen always slides down (towards the ground) regardless of the devices landscape left or landscape right orientation.

On an iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 8 the called screen quickly rotates to Upside Down (top towards the home button) and then slides off to home button side.  Again it doesn't matter which way the phone is oriented landscape left or landscape right orientation.

I have tried setting the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation, shouldAutorotate to NO, and setting the supportedInterfaceOrientations to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.  Nothing seems to make any difference at all.

My screen navigation is straight forward, I'm no using any custom transitions. It's all through standard push segues.

I need to get the screen "back" transitions working correctly again.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally discovered what was causing my screens to slide the wrong direction.  It turns out that overriding the supportedInterfaceOrientations method in the UIViewController and returning UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft confuses the transition in iOS 8 (and devices running iOS 7 also). This was needed for proper operation in iOS 7, but evidently causes problems in iOS 8.  So once I removed the code, the screen transitions began working correctly again.

Comment: `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is supposed to return values from 
`UIInterfaceOrientationMask`. You should have returned `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight`. I don't know if that would have solved your issue though, or if this was just a typo in your question.

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem. But I'll keep this in mind in case I run into this again.